# Filter 2D array by value of a particular key

Tags: php, arrays, filter

How can I filter this array to only keep items with `[category] => 1`?

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [link] => index
        [image] => spot
        [category] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [link] => test
        [image] => spotless
        [category] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [link] => differentcat
        [image] => spotly
        [category] => 1
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

You want something like this (presuming you want to keep entries with `category` 1):

```
function categoryone($var)
{
    return (is_array($var) && $var['category'] == 1);
}

print_r(array_filter($your_array, "categoryone"));
```

Comment: I have a question, how can i set the number (in this case 1) to a variable? I want to apply this function inside a for loop where 1 changes, it will not always be 1. i mean, $var['category']==$number); so how do i call this function with an argument? otherwise, i get a warning array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` that checks for the category value in a callback. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Answer (score 2):

Define a filter function like this:

```
function filter_function($var) {
    return is_array($var) && $var['category'] == 1;
}
```

… and then use array_filter() to apply this function to your array:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($my_array, 'filter_function');
```

*Edit: changed the filtering function to keep matching values instead of discarding them.*

Answer (score 0):

@pathros :

To use a different value for filtering, the solution is the following : (TESTED :-) )

```
//Define your array
$my_array = array(
  0 =>   array(
    'cat' =>         '1',
    'value' =>         'Value A'
    )
  ,
  1 =>   array(
    'cat' =>         '2',
    'value' =>         'Value B'
    )
  ,
  2 =>   array(
    'cat' =>         '0',
    'value' =>         'Value C'
    )
  ,
  3 =>   array(
    'cat' =>         '1',
    'value' =>         'Value D'
    )
  );

//Define your filtering function
function my_filtering_function($in_array) {
    return is_array($in_array) && $in_array['cat'] == $GLOBALS['filter_param_1'];
}

//TEST #1 : Set the desired value to 2
$GLOBALS['filter_param_1'] = 2;
//Filter your array to only return items that match "cat=2"
$filtered_array = array_filter($my_array, 'my_filtering_function');
e('Number of matching records : '.count($filtered_array)).'record(s)<br>'; //Will return "1 record(s)" (the second record of your array)

//TEST #2 : Set the desired value to 1
$GLOBALS['filter_param_1'] = 1;
//Filter your array to only return items that match "cat=1"
$filtered_array = array_filter($my_array, 'my_filtering_function');
e('Number of matching records : '.count($filtered_array)).'record(s)<br>'; //Will return "2 record(s)" (the first and the last of your array)
```