# Filter array of filenames against an array of banned words and an array of banned file extensions

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, filenames, blacklist

I am using PHP and I have an array of user images that I need to filter. I need to do 2 different filters:

1. Look in original array and see if each value contains a value in my "bad words" array
2. Look and see if the value in the original array ends in one of "bad extensions" values

Images Array:

```
Array  
(  
    [0] => smiles.gif  
    [1] => kittens.jpg  
    [2] => biscuits.png  
    [3] => butthead.jpg  
)  

$bad_words = array('beavis','butthead','winehouse');  
$bad_extensions = array('.gif','.tiff');
```

I would like it to return:

```
Array  
(  
    [0] => kittens.jpg  
    [1] => biscuits.png  
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering array values in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594113/filtering-array-values-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array("smiles.gif", "kittens.jpg", "biscuits.png", "butthead.jpg");

$new_arr = array_filter($array, "filter");

function filter($element) {
    $bad_words = array('beavis','butthead','winehouse');  
    $bad_extensions = array('gif','tiff');

    list($name, $extension) = explode(".", $element);
    if(in_array($name, $bad_words))
        return;

    if(in_array($extension, $bad_extensions))
        return;

    return $element;
}


echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [1] => kittens.jpg
    [2] => biscuits.png
)
```

I removed the . from your extensions tho

edit: added wicked fleas correction

Comment: Technically, you can return `$element` instead of `"{$name}.{$extension}"` as you did no manipulation of it.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure `in_array()` doesn't search like that. It determines if the string matches precisely.

Comment: @alex in_array "Returns TRUE if needle  is found in the array, FALSE otherwise". @Flea good point, ty.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd remove the periods in your extension list. It will only make the code more difficult. If you've done this, the following (untested) code should work, or at least be a start

```
$cleanArray = [];

foreach($array as $value) {

    $extension = path_info($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if (in_array($extension, $bad_extensions)) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach($bad_words as $word) {
        if (strstr($word, $value)) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $cleanArray[] = $value;


}
```

$cleanArray should have the values you want.

Here are some handy references from the PHP online docs

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php
- http://au.php.net/strstr
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function in PHP, just write a function that does the filtering you want then call

```
array_filter($array1, "custom_filter");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because case-insensitive matching is a reasonable inclusion and because `in_array()` does not have a case-insensitive mode, I'd probably just generate a regex pattern from the two arrays and let the regex engine do the tedious filtration.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cojN7))

```
$branches = implode(
    '|',
    array_merge(
        $bad_words,
        array_map(
            fn($v) => preg_quote($v, '/') . '$',
            $bad_extensions
        )
    )
);
// beavis|butthead|winehouse|\.gif$|\.tiff$
var_export(preg_grep("/$branches/i", $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT));
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'kittens.jpg',
  2 => 'biscuits.png',
)
```