# Filtering array values using integers in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, filter, integer

I am trying to filter a php array by *comparing* a field containing a unix date string ("start-unix-date") with the *current* unix time (simplified in this example as "15"). I want to keep only items where the unix date is in the future (>= than present).

Here is a simplified version of my code - based on [this filtering method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594113/):

```
$my_array = array(
    array( 'start-date-unix' => '20' ), 
    array( 'start-date-unix'  => '10')
);

$unix_now = 15;

function filter_future($var) {
    return (is_array($var) && $var['start-date-unix'] >= $unix_now)
}

$filtered_array = array_filter($my_array, "filter_future");

var_dump($filtered_array);
```

### The expected result:

The $filtered_array should keep only the item with a "start-date-unix" value of 20.

### Actual result:

That filter doesn't do anything, every value is accepted. The $filtered_array still contains both items.

### What works:

In the filter_future, if I enter the number (15) instead of the $unix_now variable, it works as expected: only the "20" item is kept.

So I suspect that there's an issue with $unix_now being a string vs an integer. I tried many methods of enforcing it being an integer but nothing seems to work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$unix_now` should be a `global` variable inside filter_future-function.

```
$unix_now = 15;

function filter_future($var) {
    global $unix_now;
    return (is_array($var) && (int) $var['start-date-unix'] >= $unix_now)
}

$filtered_array = array_filter($my_array, "filter_future");

var_dump($filtered_array);
```

The result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["start-date-unix"]=> string(2) "20" } }
```

Comment: Sure, it's just that stackoverflow imposes a 10 min delay before I could approve, and by then I was back in my workflow :)

Answer (score 1):

$unix_now is out of scope within the callback function:

Use a closure with the `use` keyword to pass the $unix_now value to the callback

```
$unix_now = 15;
$filtered_array = array_filter(
    $my_array, 
    function ($var) use ($unix_now) {
        return (is_array($var) && $var['start-date-unix'] >= $unix_now)
    }
);
```

Comment: This seems like the more elegant option out of the 4 (so far) answers (IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = array(
    array( 'start-date-unix' => '20' ), 
    array( 'start-date-unix'  => '10')
);

$unix_now = 15;

foreach ($my_array as $i => $row)
{
    if ($row['start-date-unix'] < $unix_now)
    {
        unset($my_array[$i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like below:

```
function filter_future($var) {
    $unix_now = 15;
    return (is_array($var) && $var['start-date-unix'] >= $unix_now);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move `$unix_now = 15;` inside `function filter_future`

```
function filter_future($var) {
    $unix_now = 15;
    return (is_array($var) && $var['start-date-unix'] >= $unix_now);
}
```

`$unix_now` inside your function is not recognize outside variable `$unix_now`. So put it inside your function is better

Comment: Actually that function, $unix_now, is being defined at a totally different place in my code. My example here was a very simplified version.